# Yellow Jacaranda or weed?

Tags: trees

This sprouted in my yard in South West Florida. Not sure what it is. The yellow flower is similar in shape to bleefing heart. The stalk is very green and it seems to grow quite fast.[image]

Comment: what area of the world do you live in?

Comment: We live in SWFL, United States

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Partridge Pea. [*Chamaecrista fasciculata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamaecrista_fasciculata) 
Common in most of the Eastern US.
Here's a decent image:
[image]